# ASP.NET Check new mail on Lotus Notes/Domino server

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there a way to **check new mail** on a Lotus **Notes/Domino** server in **ASP.NET 3.5+**, for multiple users. Users are logged in with there Windows Domain account into the ASPx application.

Answer (score 2):

Given, that the Domino servers are also on Windows and they have [SPNEGO](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/dominowiki.nsf/dx/Deploying_SPNEGO) activated for SSO, you have several options, depending on what you mean by "check new mail".

If you want to include the Inbox in your ASP.Net app eg. as an iframe, you can use [iNotes portal mode](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21390473) to accomplish that.

If you are on Domino 8.5.3, you can use the [REST services of the new extension library](http://www.openntf.org/blogs/openntf.nsf/d6plinks/NHEF-8JGGPE) to access the Inbox contents via a few REST calls and Json. See the link for more infos.

If you want to access the "new mail" in the backend of your ASP.Net app, you are problably out of luck, as the information about "new/unread" mail is stored per user and you would need the ID-File/password or http password of the user to access that information.

But maybe you could provide more info, so we can give better advice.

Comment: The ASPx application in question is a Intranet site, in one corner there is going to be a link to Domino webmail with the text [You have {n} new mail]. The biggest problem i can see is, there is not going to be any SSO.

Comment: Without SSO, there is no way to get the info, how many "new" mails a user has.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes you can, but it's not a straight up webservice call. I'm not aware of any turn key configuration that would enable this. So, you will need to "roll your own" service. If so, then you'll be interested in "Unread marks" or "Unread email". This is a unique function to Lotus Notes and is not exposed as service in Java or .Net. But you can get around it by using the "[GetAllUnreadEntries](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETALLUNREADENTRIES.html)" method in the Lotus Notes object API.

Using this method, you can programmatically emulate it without too much complexity. Is it possible for you to try this:

Can you implement in an ASP.Net application a "last Checked" date/time value that is set when you traverse the inbox of Domino mail account ?

Now whilst looping through the inbox, get the created date of each document.

In the case of email in a Lotus Notes database, this is the date the email hit the account. So it should be a fairly reliable means of determining the arrival date of the email.

The created date property is under the NotesDocument object as "[created](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATED_PROPERTY_DOC.html)". This should return a date/time value that you can use. Any document that is newer than the "last checked" value would therefore be new mail.

If you have a particularly large inbox to loop through, you can get the inbox object (which can be treated like a view), and also use "[GetAllUnreadEntries](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETALLUNREADENTRIES.html)" method on the NotesView object.

Links to example code are in the links above.